# Search icon action button not displaying in action bar - no way to access search function

Tags: java, android, xml, search

I've created a search function for a RecyclerView using the following as a guide:

How to filter a RecyclerView with a SearchView

I'm unable to test it, because all that displays is the app bar with the app title. I was expecting (hoping!) to see a search icon action button, which I clicked to open a search field. (similar to the demo in the attached).

I have got the following code that applies to launching the search menu:

search_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
android:title="@string/search_title"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
android:showAsAction="always|ifroom"
/>
</menu>
```

This is the code from my fragment:

```
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
 inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

 final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

 final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```

}

I've gone through the android developer guides, but still can't figure it out. Can anyone advise if I am missing anything? Or have any idea why it does not display? I am completely stumped!

Comment: Is this from an activity or a fragment?

Comment: It's from a fragment!

Comment: did you call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` somewhere in `onCreateView()`?

Comment: ah, no, I didn't! But I just tried that and it throws a Null Pointer Exception :(                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: You are trying to cast `search icon` to `searchview` you need to make changes in your toolbar directly.

Comment: See, adding `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` has made the system call `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, so you're a step closer.

Comment: @krislarson - Yes! One step closer :) Not quite there, but hopefully soon!

Comment: What class does your `Activity` extend? `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Try changing to `android:showAsAction="always|ifroom"` in your menu XML to `app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"`

Answer (score 0):

Dont override any method related to Menu like `onMenuCreated` or `onMenuItemSelected`

Add this code in your MainActivity XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/search"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Then in your fragment, access the search view just like you access other views using the ID.

you are trying to cast search icon to search view, make a custom layout, it will work then.

Comment: Thanks @MohammedAtif - I really appreciate your help. I'm not sure I fully understand. I modified my code to yours above, but wondering if I still need to call setOnQueryTextListener() somewhere? Also, where would the above xml go? and does that affect what I call in the onCreateOptionsMenu() methid?

Comment: Sorry for that unstructured answer. If you are using SearchView, then you dont override first two methods, You can directly access it like other views from your OnActivityCreated or OnCreateView, etc. and that XML will be part of your MainActivity XML,

Comment: Thanks @Mohammed for your help. I think I am getting closer! I haven't got the above two methods, but can I still override onCreateOptionsMenu() ? I have put the above in my main_activity but when trying to access the Search View, I have no view object i.e. SearchView searchView = (SearchView) view_one.findViewById(R.id.searchView_main); Where should that view_one object? come from? Thanks for being so patient

Comment: Generally when you create your custom toolbar, you dont override `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, Just for your understanding, In android studio, create new NavigationDrawerActivity project, and check the activity_main layout. Then mix and match the codes according to your convinience.